# Drawing or add graphic

Tags: android, android-drawable

I would like to Draw a Picture like this in android, but I don't know how I would go on with it. I want to Draw it because I don't want to add different versinos of if for every screen density. Can you help me in the right direction? As you can see both the background and the item has a gradient fill.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a white and a blue (with gradient) images programmatically. You also need to draw the mask (triangular shapes). For that I suggest you to read irregular shapes series of Mark Allison blog. Here's the link for the first part:

[Irregular Shapes Part 1](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/irregular-shapes-part-1/)

Basically you need to draw white image, and then on top of that the mask-applied blue image.